# Show effect only when that section is reached in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a chart made using d3.js:

[Code for chart](https://jsfiddle.net/qp7L1hob/)

I have put this chart within a website.

[website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

Problem is that in the above website, when you scroll through the page to the "teamchart" section, I don't see the effect of the chart. When you refresh the page, you can see the chart role the effect.

I want the chart to role and show the effect, when I reach that section of the page or when I use the nav bar, click "teamchart" and reach that section.

I used the below JavaScript code, but it's repeating it continuously:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  //Basically your position in the page
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  //How far down (in pixels) you want the user to be when the effect to starts, eg. 500
  var y = 500;
  if (x > y) {
     //Put your effect functions in here.
  }
});
```

Fiddle related to the website:

[My code related to website](https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/6/) (experiment here)

Comment: Please note that if you have a problem with a website you are working on, it is not sufficient to link the demo site in your question. This is because we want questions here to last forever, but it is unlikely that the demo site will be preserved. At the time you remove that server from the internet, this question may no longer be useful to future readers, since they will not be able to see a representation of the problem you had. Are you able to amend the question so the problem appears in the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, your problem is the part where the animation keeps playing.

this is because every time you scroll the page, to a value greater then 500, you actually repeating your code.

Easy solution: place a flag to signal 'alreadyAnimated'

```
var g_pieChartAnimated=false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  //Basically your position in the page
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  //How far down (in pixels) you want the user to be when the effect to starts, eg. 500
  var y = 500;
  if (!g_pieChartAnimated && (x > y)) {
      g_pieChartAnimated = true;
      //Put your effect functions in here.
  }
});
```

Second solution (bit faster):
is to detach the event handler once it did what you want.

```
function onScroll_AnimateChart() {
  //Basically your position in the page
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  //How far down (in pixels) you want the user to be when the effect to starts, eg. 500
  var y = 500;
  if (!g_pieChartAnimated && (x > y)) {
      $(document).off('scroll', onScroll_AnimateChart); // remove myself from the event handlers, so it won't be called again.
      //Put your effect functions in here.
  }
}

$(document).on('scroll', onScroll_AnimateChart);
```

Comment: Based on the fiddle it doesn't look like the animation is repeating - it gets run before the user has scrolled to that section of the page. (**Sorry I didn't see where she said it was repeating.. disregard ;-)**

Comment: can someone correct the syntax on the second snippet ?

Comment: @jane glad to help, btw: i corrected the syntax on my second approach.

Comment: I have a problem here,the replay button inn the chart isnot working,when i use ur ist solution as the code.What may be the reason this is happening ? @TomerW

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** 
I missed where you said the animation was repeating - @Tomer W solution is correct.

Similar to what @Tomer W posted, but run the chart function (or the chart the whatever function triggers the animation) in your `scroll handler`:

```
var chartInit = false;
var handler = function() {
  var y = 500;
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (x > y && !charInit) {
   charInit = true;
   someD3ChartStuff();
  }
};

$(document).scroll(handler);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the 2 following solutions for your issue, hope it helps!

### 1 - Pure css + jQuery solution

```
$(window).on('scroll' , function(){
    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    element_pos = $(".chart-wrapper").offset().top + $(".chart-wrapper").height() ;
    if (scroll_pos > element_pos) {
        $(".chart-wrapper").addClass('animation');
    };
})
```

and after that manipulate your animation in the class `animation`

### 2- Wow.JS Library

1- Download the script [here](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)
2- Download the animate.css [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) 
3- Use this snippet as example and understand how it works

```
<script src="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>


<div class="wow bounceInLeft animated">
              <h2>animated heading</h2>
</div>
```

Obs.: There's a bunch of animations that you can use with this library + animate.css just use any of the classes below and put the class `wow` also

Here's the list

```
bounce
flash
pulse
rubberBand
shake
headShake
swing
tada
wobble
jello
bounceIn
bounceInDown
bounceInLeft
bounceInRight
bounceInUp
bounceOut
bounceOutDown
bounceOutLeft
bounceOutRight
bounceOutUp
fadeIn
fadeInDown
fadeInDownBig
fadeInLeft
fadeInLeftBig
fadeInRight
fadeInRightBig
fadeInUp
fadeInUpBig
fadeOut
fadeOutDown
fadeOutDownBig
fadeOutLeft
fadeOutLeftBig
fadeOutRight
fadeOutRightBig
fadeOutUp
fadeOutUpBig
flipInX
flipInY
flipOutX
flipOutY
lightSpeedIn
lightSpeedOut
rotateIn
rotateInDownLeft
rotateInDownRight
rotateInUpLeft
rotateInUpRight
rotateOut
rotateOutDownLeft
rotateOutDownRight
rotateOutUpLeft
rotateOutUpRight
hinge
rollIn
rollOut
zoomIn
zoomInDown
zoomInLeft
zoomInRight
zoomInUp
zoomOut
zoomOutDown
zoomOutLeft
zoomOutRight
zoomOutUp
slideInDown
slideInLeft
slideInRight
slideInUp
slideOutDown
slideOutLeft
slideOutRight
slideOutUp
```